# Java annotation processing basics

Tags: java, annotations

I have used the simple annotations given to us in the JDK and by other libraries such as hibernate, but I've never written my own. Can someone help me decide if an annotation is the proper way to do this?

I want to annotate a method like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(5)
public void foo() {
     methodThatMightTakeLongerThan5();
}
```

When foo takes longer than 5 seconds, print a message to my log file. Is this possible with Annotations?  Is that the preferred implementation?

Going a bit further...I'd like to be able to modify the value passed to the annotation via JMX bean so that I can modify it at runtime if I want to.  Is that possible/preferred?

Comment: This may be pretty involved.  Are you looking to use a JSR269 annotation processor to accomplish this or just standard reflection?

Comment: That's the thing, I really don't have much experience with annotation processors.  Any light you can shed on the subject is helpful.  I have visited a few sites I found by googling, but the light bulb has not turned on yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could put `methodThatMightTakeLongerThan5();` inside a Thread, run the thread in `foo()`, wait for 5 seconds with `Thread.sleep(5000);`, then check if the thread is done. If not, print whatever you need. I assume there is a way to check if a thread is running, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like that, but the reason I lean toward the annotation is that it's simple and re-usable.  I have several places where this would be useful.